# MS Outlook version 2208

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meetings

is there a way to forward a recurring meeting to a colleague e.g. for a certain period only? If e.g.  I am invited to a daily meeting Mon-Fri until to year end, but need my colleague to attend the meeting only during my holiday.

Answer (score 1):

From
[Outlook Forward a meeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/forward-a-meeting-94f2df68-8109-4334-8bfa-f5c013dc1578) :

> To forward a meeting or meeting series that’s on your calendar:
>
> 1. In the calendar, double-click the meeting to open it.
>
>    - For a recurring meeting, click **Just this one** to forward a single meeting in the series or click **The entire series** to forward
>      the entire series.
> 2. On the main meeting menu (either Meeting, **Meeting Occurrence** or **Meeting Series**), in the **Actions** group, click **Forward > Forward**.
> 3. In the **To** box, enter the email address or addresses of the people you want to forward the meeting to, and then click **Send**.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is about forwarding the whole series. But I'd like to forward only on certain part (certain time period) of the occurence period. e.g. if the original meeting invitation  is scheduled to occur each working days during a calendar year, I'd like to forward the invitation to my substitute for one month.  I wonder what would the "Assign policy" > "Retention policy > 1 month" do?

Comment: Retention policies control how long your messages will be saved, so not connected. For forwarding some specific meetings, you will need to forward each occurrence separately. Otherwise, you'll need to write a VBA macro, which is much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's currently not possible using the built-in options available Outlook. So, you would have to forward the entire recurring meeting or forward each instance separately.

Another workaround I can think of is to share the occurrences via CSV file:

1. Export your calendar to CSV file, set the data range to make sure this recurring meeting is included.
2. Open the CSV file in Excel, delete all unwanted lines, leave only the occurrences that you want the colleague to see.
3. Share the modified version of the CSV file to the colleague so that he/she can import it to his/her calendar.

[Import and export Outlook email, contacts, and calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-and-export-outlook-email-contacts-and-calendar-92577192-3881-4502-b79d-c3bbada6c8ef)

[Export Calendar into CSV Exchaneg 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/255510/export-calendar-into-csv-exchaneg-2016)